# Is there a way to save or export Screentime data?

Tags: macos, ios, data, screen-time

Screentime on Mac and iOS records data every day but it only keeps the data for a few weeks. Obviously the data must be stored somewhere, is there a way to access it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Hackeron No. Doesn't seem to be possible without custom code.

Comment: I’m fine with custom code, where do I find this code?

Comment: perhaps if we can make use of the Screen Time API, someone can write a app that removes the 4 week limit. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/screentime